# How to replace string in dataframe column by list of strings

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I need to convert string in dataframe column to list of strings.
I have this info in a column:

| index | 0 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Wire cup brush dm 65 |

I want to split the string in column 0 to words like this:

```
c = df_loop_t[0][0].split()
Meanwhile non split value (' Wire cup brush dm 65') is stored as b = df_loop_t[0][0]
```

to get

```
['Wire', 'cup', 'brush', 'dm', '65', 'mm']
```

Then I tried to replace the existing string (b) with the new list of values(c) with replace:

```
df_loop_t[0][0].replace(b,c)
```

But it doesnt work, nor other ways that I tried... What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works:

```python
df_loop_t.at[1,0]=b
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d=["Wire cup brush dm 65"]
df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['0'])
l=df['0'].tolist()
for i in l:
    print(i.split(" "))
```